How are the expressions for $\mu$ and $\beta$ obtained?
Given $E^{(p)} = \frac{N}{\beta} + \frac{N\mu}{\sqrt{\beta^2 (\mu^2 - 4\mu)}}$ and $n^{(p)} = \frac{N}{\sqrt{\beta^2 (\mu^2 - 4\mu)}}$, how are the expressions for $\beta$ and $\mu$ obtained in terms of $E^{(p)}$ and $n^{(p)}$?
I am supposed to get $\mu = \frac{{E^{(p)}}^{2}}{2E^{(p)} n^{(p)} - 4{n^{(p)}}^{2}}$ and $\beta = \frac{2N(E^{(p)} - 2n^{(p)})}{{E^{(p)}}^{2} - 4E^{(p)}n^{(p)}}$.

In my attempt, I notice that I can substitute $n^(p)$ into the equation for $E^{(p)}$.
$$E^{(p)} = \frac{N}{\beta} + \mu n^{(p)}$$
Then $\mu = \frac{E^{(p)} - \frac{N}{\beta}}{n^{(p)}}$, but a $\beta$ term remains. From $n^{(p)}$, $\beta^2 = \frac{N}{n^{(p)}\sqrt{\mu^2 - 4\mu}}$. I could then substitute, but then I have the $\mu$ problem...

You were on the right track. Start with $E^{(p)} = \frac{N}{\beta} + \mu n^{(p)}$ and rearrange the given equation of $n^{(p)}$ to get $\frac{N}{\beta} = n^{(p)}\sqrt{u^2-4\mu}$. Combining those gives:
$$\begin{eqnarray} E^{(p)} & = & n^{(p)} \sqrt{\mu^2 - 4\mu} + \mu n^{(p)} \\
\frac{E^{(p)}}{n^{(p)}} - \mu & = & \sqrt{\mu^2 - 4\mu} \\
\left(\frac{E^{(p)}}{n^{(p)}} - \mu\right)^2 & = & \mu^2 - 4\mu
\end{eqnarray}$$
and by expanding and rearranging the last line you should be able to get the required formula for $\mu$, which you can then substitute into one of the other formulas to give you $\beta$.
